# List all the users with the count of drivers they registered

Tags: php, sql, laravel, web, laravel-5.4

i have tow models `User`and `Driver` the `user` can register any number of drivers `drivers`

in drivers table i have `agent_id`, i want to list all the `users` with the count of the drivers they registered

in my Usercontroller i want to get the count of the drivers registered by the agents

```
public function index(Request $request) 
{
    $users = User::all();

    $registration_centers = RegistrationCenter::all();

    $drivers_registered = Driver::where('agent_id' , $agent_id)->count();  //something like this but i don't have agent_id to query with

    return view('agents', compact('users', 'registration_centers', drivers_registered));
}
```

Drver Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Driver extends Model
{
   use SoftDeletes;

   protected $fillable = ['agent_id','registration_center','event_name','registration_id','profile_photo','first_name','last_name',];

}
```

and User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Driver;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'phone_number','password','address_city_village','address_state','image','registration_center','status'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token','created_at','updated_at','deleted_at'];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

i wan to disply all the `users` in a list view with the drivers count of each users

```
<ul>
    @foreach (users as user)
    <li>User: {{user->name}}  
         Total Drivers: {{$user->drivers_count}}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

thank you

Comment: share `Driver` and `User` model ?

Comment: thank you so much for your time, i have updated my post

Comment: I suggest to use : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: @Niklesh  yes i was looking into that, but i din't get the part, how i'l get the drivers count of each user with out any `agent_id`, i'm a kinda confused. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `agent_id` is the key that relates the User to the Driver... you're pretty close to what I think you're asking for.

However, in the first line of the index method of your UserController, I would update

```
$users = User::all();
```

to

```
$users = User::withCount('drivers')->all();
```

and add the drivers relationship to the User model.

So the user model with the relationship added will now be

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'phone_number','password','address_city_village','address_state','image','registration_center','status'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token','created_at','updated_at','deleted_at'];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function drivers(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Driver', 'agent_id');
    }

}
```

You may be able to remove the line below from your controller but that's up to you...

```
$drivers_registered = Driver::where('agent_id' , $agent_id)->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Example AgentController:

```
 public function index(Request $request, $agenId){
        $users = User::all();
        $registration_centers = RegistrationCenter::all();
        $drivers_registered = Driver::where('agent_id' , $agenId)->count(); 
        return view('agents', compact('users', 'registration_centers', 
        'drivers_registered'));
    }

    this blade 
    <p> {{ $drivers_registered }} </p>
```

Comment: thank you for your time, here i'm not passing any `agent_id`, i want to display all the `agents` in a list view with the count of drivers each agents registered